# Python: Update dictionary with multiple variables?

Tags: python, django

I've got this code:

```py
    def update_amounts(self):
        container = {}

        a = {'a': self.a_amount} if self.a_mount or self.a_amount is None else {'': ''}
        container.update(a)
        b = {'b': self.b_amount} if self.b_amount or self.b_amount is None else {'':''}
        container.update(b)
        c = {'c': self.c_amount} if self.c_amount or self.c_amount is None else {'':''}
        container.update(c)

        return container
```

And I wanted to know if its possible to do the dict update more efficient than calling the update function three times?

Thanks in regard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Python 3.9+, you can use pipe symbol `|` to combine multiple dictionaries

```py
    def update_amounts(self):
        # container = {}
        a = {'a': self.a_amount} if self.a_mount or self.a_amount is None else {'': ''}
        # container.update(a)
        b = {'b': self.b_amount} if self.b_amount or self.b_amount is None else {'':''}
        # container.update(b)
        c = {'c': self.c_amount} if self.c_amount or self.c_amount is None else {'':''}
        # container.update(c)
        container = a|b|c
        return container
```

Or, you can just pass the unpacked values for each of the dictionaries to the update method at last:

```py
    def update_amounts(self):
        container = {}
        .
        .
        .
        container.update(**a, **b, **c)
        return container
```